# What is the logic behind "@dotnet-bot test this please" in DotNet repro on GitHub?

Tags: .net, github, bots, devops

I noticed .NET team often asks their github bot to test something, like this: `@dotnet-bot test this please`, e.g. [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/32859#issuecomment-431328936).

What's the logic behind this? Can I create my own bot like that and integrate it with my release pipeline (e.g., with AppVyeor)?

Comment: If your CI system can be appropriately scripted, you probably don't need a bot and would be better off without one.

Comment: @bk2204 I think it's cool to have both option, I imagine the bot just invokes the proper script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet-bot` an automated bot account used for the `dotnet/corefx` and `dotnet/coreclr` repos.
(you have other such accounts: [`airbim-bot`](https://github.com/airbim-bot), [`Favware-bot`](https://github.com/Favware-bot), and [more](https://github.com/topics/bot-account))

As mentioned in [Types of GitHub accounts](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/types-of-github-accounts):

> User accounts are intended for humans, but you can give one to a robot, such as a continuous integration bot, if necessary.

It is an online instance from [`microsoft/botframework-sdk`](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk), which you can test with [`microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator), for the [`microsoft/botframework-sdk`](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk)

> With the Bot Framework SDK, developers can build bots that converse free-form or with guided interactions including using simple text or rich cards that contain text, images, and action buttons.

> Developers can model and build sophisticated conversation using their favorite programming languages including C#, JS, Python and Java or using **[Bot Framework Composer](https://aka.ms/bfcomposer)**, an open-source, visual authoring canvas for developers and multi-disciplinary teams to design and build conversational experiences with Language Understanding, QnA Maker and sophisticated composition of bot replies (Language Generation).

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/master/docs/media/GitHubBannerV2.gif]

Comment: You can add webhooks to a project to be notified on issue comments: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#issue_comment